# (Real Analysis) Integration of two functions

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, integration, banach-spaces

Note ($\Omega,A,\mu)$ is a finite additive space. Let $f\in \bar S(A, \mathbb{R})$ and $y\in Y$ where $Y$ is Banach space. Prove $\int _\Omega yf d\mu = y \int _\Omega f d\mu$. Also, for any $X\in A$, prove $\int_X yf d\mu = f\int_X f d\mu$.

Hint provided: Go define a linear transform $T: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow Y$ then find a nice theorem.

Comment: What is ${\overline S}(A, \mathbb{R})$?

Comment: You haven't defined any of the symbols here. Also, in your last statement, you have $X \in A$, but then there is no $X$ in the expression.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot that notation is nonstandard. I believe it stands for the closure of the collection of valued simple functions on $\Omega$. Sorry for the mistake about X, I have fixed that now. $\Omega$ is a set, $A$ is an algebra of subsets of $\Omega$. It is all mostly technical so that the main axioms of the integral follow, such as linearity.

Comment: The closure in which sense?

Comment: For any sequence of functions $f_n$ in the space, $f_n \rightarrow f$ converges uniformly. I believe that is it, unless I'm mistaken. I'm still new to this material, and so the definitions are confusing to me as well. I'm not sure how to go about proving this with a linear transformation. I'd start with the route of using sequence of functions $f_n$ and $y_n$ but then that's where I'm still not sure where to proceed.